# Python 3 using matplotlib to display pie chart with percentages , TypeError

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I am making a simple pie chart with matplotlib with only 2 segments. When I add in a variable 'fracs' at the start of the pie command I get an error regarding the "explode" argument. Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataFile = open("data.txt") #open the file with the data
bigData = dataFile.readlines() #read it into a variable
bigData2 = [] # make a second list

for line in bigData: #iterate through bigData and make bigData2, a list with lists in it ( 2D list? )
    aData = line.split(",")
    bigData2.append(aData)

transfer = [] #make transfer list holder
nonTransfer = [] #make nonTransfer list holder

for i in bigData2: #iterate through bigData2 and sort based on contents
    if i[2] == "Request Transferred\n":
        transfer.append(i)
    if i[2] != "Request Transferred\n":
        nonTransfer.append(i)

trans = len(transfer) #get lengths of the lists
nTrans = len(nonTransfer)

total = trans+nTrans

percentTrans = int((trans/total)*100) #makes percentage values
percentnTrans = int((nTrans/total)*100)

fracs = [percentTrans,percentnTrans] #make fraction variable
print(percentnTrans, ",", percentTrans)

#Setup and make the pie chart

labels = 'transfer', 'nonTransfer'
sizes = trans, nTrans
colors = 'red', 'blue'
explode = (0, 0.1)
plt.pie(fracs , sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, shadow=True, startangle=90)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Most of this can be ignored in my opinion. The two lines I feel may be the source of the problem are when 'fracs' is defined and the plt.pie() line.

Traceback is as follows :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   92 , 7   File "C:/Users/LewTo002/Desktop/serReq/dataEdit.py", line 37,
>   in 
>       plt.pie(fracs , sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, shadow=True, startangle=90) TypeError: pie() got
>   multiple values for argument 'explode'

I was basing what I was doing off of ( http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html ) and ( http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html ) with the assistance of this documentation ( http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie )

Upon further reflection I do feel that the way I defined 'fracs' to be the culprit but I am not entirely sure how ( or if ) I went wrong there. I do appreciate your time and assistance regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the matplotlib documentation, the `pie()` function takes one argument and then keyword arguments.

```
matplotlib.pyplot.pie(x, explode=None, labels=None, colors=None, autopct=None,    pctdistance=0.6, shadow=False, labeldistance=1.1, startangle=None, radius=None, counterclock=True, wedgeprops=None, textprops=None, center=(0, 0), frame=False, hold=None, data=None)
```

In your example, you are calling the `pie()` function with the following call

```
plt.pie(fracs , sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, shadow=True, startangle=90)
```

Basically, the `pie()` function expects only one normal argument but because you provide two (`fracs` and `sizes`), your second one gets assigned to the keyword `explode`. Thus, Python throws you the following error `TypeError: pie() got multiple values for argument 'explode'` because you are assigning values to `explode` twice.

---

### Edit 1

If you want the percentages in each wedge, then use the `autopct` keyword argument when calling the `pie()` function. This is shown in this [example](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html) and explained in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html).

> autopct: [ None | format string | format function ]
>   If not None, is a string or function used to label the wedges with their numeric value. The label will be placed inside the wedge. If it is a format string, the label will be fmt%pct. If it is a function, it will be called.

The value shown in each wedge will correspond to that given in `fracs`. If you want to use a different label, as defined in `sizes`, then I'd guess you'd have to plot a second `pie()` on top and use those values, then set the `colors` kwarg to `None`, which would only show the labels.

Comment: Ah I see, ( http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html ) is the only one of those links that mentions 'sizes' I just noticed... sizes isn't listed in the 'docs' link... When I remove 'sizes' the error disappears but I don't have the percentage labels on the pie chart segments.

Comment: @ToddLewden Please see **Edit 1** in my post.